# TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureInWindow' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Environment:

```
Windows 10
Node js: 10.x
Expo: 35.0.0
React: 16.8
React-native: 0.62.0
React-navigation: 3.0.7
```

A simple app developed to test navigation on android app, facing the below error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureInWindow' of undefined"

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: getting the same error here after I updated from react-native 0.59 to 0.62. Still haven't found a solution

Comment: For me the problem seems to be related to the version of react-native-safe-area-view that react-navigation is using is incompatible with react-native 0.62.

Haven't tried yet but I think updating react-navigation should solve the issue

Comment: Thank you @Hoffmann. It is resolved with react-navigation@5.x It was due to version conflict between react-native and react-navigation. Now, they are updated.

Comment: No problem @Chetan, for anyone else running into this, updating to react-navigation v4 also works (v4 is not as big of a breaking change as v5)

Answer (score -2):

**install react-native-safe-area-view**

following is the command to install react-native-safe-area-view:

> npm i react-native-safe-area-view

for more info:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-view

Comment: OP could probably benifit from an explanation of why he receives this error and how the package you linked to solves this.

Comment: React Navigation internally use react-native-safe-area-view and the measureInWindow is from the safe area view. so it cause error without it