# Error with task: Cannot read property 'measureInWindow' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-native-safe-area-view

I am trying to setup an application with @react-navigation.

I have installed all the required dependencies:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.0",
react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
```

When launching the application I receive errors regarding 'measureInWindow'.

`wrapNativeSuper.js:10 Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureInWindow' of undefined`

This would appear to relate to the `react-native-safe-area-context` per some research but I am unable to figure out why that doesn't work. I have pod installed since adding the libraries and rebuilt the application, but the same error persists. If I remove `react-native-safe-area-context` then react-navigation will complain it is not added.

This question is related but the answer suggests updating react-navigation and I am on the latest version: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureInWindow' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006845/typeerror-cannot-read-property-measureinwindow-of-undefined) - This question also mentions `react-native-safe-area-view` but I believe react-navigation no longer uses this in favour of -safe-area-context.

This issue on react-navigation seems to relate (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7933) but it suggests react-native-safe-area-view is in use and there is a new version (that is not published?)

Comment: did you find a fix or workaround for this?